Vue 3 conversion to <script setup>
I tried to convert this code to  and don't know exactly what to do with the const. Can somebody show me the way:
setup() {
    const {
      // methods
      show, onHide, changeIndex,
      // refs
      visibleRef, indexRef, imgsRef
    } = useEasyLightbox({
      // src / src[]
      imgs: [
        'http://via.placeholder.com/250x150',
        'http://via.placeholder.com/300x150',
        'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
      ],
      // initial index
      initIndex: 0
    })

    return {
      visibleRef,
      indexRef,
      imgsRef,
      show,
      onHide
    }
  }


Just take the contents of setup() (except the return part) and place it inside <script setup>. That's it.

Mainly,
<script setup>
// stuff here
</script>

is a shorthand macro for:
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    // stuff here
    return {
      // things from stuff the template needs
    }
  }
})

It's a bit more than that (it accepts imports and you have all the <script setup> goodies (defineProps, defineEmits, defineModel, etc...) but, at it's core, it's a way to write code in a more concise way.

So, in your case, it should look like:
<script setup>
import useEasyLightbox from 'path/or/package'
const { show, onHide, changeIndex, visibleRef, indexRef, imgsRef } =
  useEasyLightbox({
    imgs: [
      'http://via.placeholder.com/250x150',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/300x150',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
    ],
    initIndex: 0
  })
</script>

, with optional lang="ts" param.
Important: some things are not possible with <script setup>. Do not aim to transform all your component definitions from defineComponent() to <script setup>. Treat it as an alternate syntax and only use it where it makes things easier, more readable, cleaner.

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useEasyLightbox } from 'path-to-useEasyLightbox' // Adjust the import path

const {
  show,
  onHide,
  changeIndex,
  visibleRef,
  indexRef,
  imgsRef
} = useEasyLightbox({
  imgs: [
    'http://via.placeholder.com/250x150',
    'http://via.placeholder.com/300x150',
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
  ],
  initIndex: 0
})
</script>

